Replacing kitchen faucet supply lines
I'm replacing a kitchen faucet that has older supply lines.  How do I remove/replace these supply lines? Thanks


I think there was a similar question a few months ago.  I think the answer was to remove the pipe and shut off valve together.  Those hoses are built into the valve as one piece.  A wrench where the hose is and a wrench on the bigger nut to turn.  Main water valve needs turning off.
